# I can't manage to install any ocaml modules

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to install a linear programming solver in ocaml, but i can't get any modules to work

I found this : https://github.com/Gbury/Ocaml-simplex
and this : https://github.com/smimram/ocaml-glpk

I'm just following what's written to do (make / make install) but evertytime after the installation, when i try to `open Glpk` or `open Simplex` it's not working. In fact even the examples files included are not working

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if those modules are just not working

Please help me I'm becoming mad.

Additional information on my problem:

I'm on Debian, the last version I guess. To install the modules, I downloaded the zip files, i installed the required modules, then unzipped, `./configure`, `make`, `make install`, just what's written on GitHub.

But then when i open an example test files, which begins by `open Glpk` (the module I'm trying to install), when i try to compile i've an error :

```
  open Glpk
       ^^^^
Error: Unbound module Glpk
```

I mean I've found 3 modules to make linear programming solver:

- https://github.com/OCamlPro-Iguernlala/ocplib-simplex
- https://github.com/Gbury/Ocaml-simplex
- https://github.com/smimram/ocaml-glpk

And I can't get any of them to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! "It's not working" is very unspecific - please [edit] your question and add the error message / feedback you get from ocaml when trying to use these modules. Also, please add information about your OS and your OCaml version.

Comment: I'm on Debian. To install the modules i've simply followed what was said on github, unzip files, install requirements, then ./configure make make install. Then when i open the example files and try to compile them, there's an error on the "open Glpk" line, and the error says "unbound module Glpk"

Comment: Please don't add crucial information in comments. [Edit] your question instead. Also, add the information which example you're trying to run plus the complete error message.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, your issue is not installing libraries but using them. Once you have installed a library, you still need to inform the compiler on where are the compiled interfaces files (.cmi) for this library, and which object files should be linked (aka .cm(x)o and .cm(x)a) .

It will be much easier to let a package manager (like opam) and a build tool (like dune) take care of those minutiæ.

For instance, with opam and dune, you can first install ocplib-simplex:

```
opam install simplex
```

Then building a executable from a `main.ml` file using this library can be done with a dune file

```
(executable (name main) (libraries ocplib-simplex) )
```

and a call to

```
 dune build main.exe
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot. I managed to "opam install simplex" even tho i had to install a lot of dependencies. But then how do you make "dune file" ? DO i simply need to write this in a text file ? I tried but it's not working and i can't find how to do it on google ..

Comment: Just creating a `dune` file in the same folder as the `main.ml` file should work?

Comment: Oh ok i though it was a specific file extention .. Anyway i'm giving up on this, it worked for ocplib-simplex, but then i had to install Core and now i have errors with "Core.make" and i can't find what is it and even if i find what is it, there's litteraly 0 documentation on the library .... Anyway thx

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get Glpk working in no time. I think you should learn a bit about [OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org/), the OCaml Package Manager. Its purpose is exactly to make library installation as easy as possible. Here's a step-by-step:

## Prerequisites

I'm going to assume you have OPAM installed. If this is not the case, you'll find the information you need [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html). The easiest way to get OPAM working is to execute the following in a shell:

```sh
sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh) && \
  opam init && \
  eval $(opam env)
```

## Installing Glpk

First, I tried to install Glpk as is.

```
opam install glpk
```

This failed with following error:

```
<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build glpk 0.1.8
└─ 
╶─ No changes have been performed

The packages you requested declare the following system dependencies. Please make sure they are installed before retrying:
    libglpk-dev
```

This is because the OCaml library Glpk is actually a binding to a system library which needs to be installed separately. On Debian, you can use `apt` to do this.

```
sudo apt install libglpk-dev
```

Then I retried installing Glpk.

```
opam install glpk
```

It succeeded. Great.

## Requiring Glpk

Now that the Glpk library is installed, you need to require it in order to make it available.

### In a REPL

When using the OCaml toplevel, you need to use the following commands in order to require Glpk.

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "glpk";;
```

### In a project

If you want to use libraries in a fully-fledged project (with multiple files, executables and whatnot), you should use a build system. The most popular OCaml build system today is [Dune](https://github.com/ocaml/dune), which Octachron covered in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515036/3092183).

## Further considerations

You should consider reading [Real World OCaml](http://dev.realworldocaml.org/), a great book that teaches from the ground up everything you need to know to build software with OCaml.